# Javascript days +/- from today

Tags: javascript, date

For a datepicker I need two dates:
from: today - 7 days,
to: today + 7 days.

I get a currentDate with:

```
  var toDay = new Date();
  var curr_date = toDay.getDate();
  var curr_month = toDay.getMonth();
  curr_month++;
  var curr_year = toDay.getFullYear();
  var toDay = (curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year);
```

How to get `7 days+` and `7 days-` dates ? **With corresponding month!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment, You can use following code

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 7);
var nextWeekDate = ((myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear());

myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() -7 );
var prevWeekDate = ((myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear());
```

[**Modified Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb2ES/)

Comment: No you can't! 
In this case you get:

`Thu Nov 07 2013 15:40:32 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time) (index):23

Sun Nov 24 2013 15:40:32 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time) (index):26`


But the month is the same!

Comment: @A1exandr, Can you provide input and expected output. Its not clear what you want

Comment: Today is `10/31/2013` if I add 7 days I need `11/07/2013`, not `10/07/2013` or `10/38/2013`. Same if `-7`. Thanks! Point is to get the right month if adding 7 or -7 ginving us a date of another month.

Comment: @A1exandr, I have updated answer and added a new demo. And you will get in `11/07/2013` format. Check console

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```
nextWeek.setDate(toDay.getDate() + 7);
lastWeek.setDate(toDay.getDate() - 7);
```

Comment: This will change dates, but the month stays the same. So if date is 31 and we add 7 days, what would be the month?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript saves a date as the number of milliseconds since midnight on january 1st 1970. You can get this time by calling "getTime()" on the Date object. You can then add 7X24X60X60X1000 to get 7 days later, or substract them for 7 days earlier represented in milliseconds. Then call Date.setTime() again.

edit: both these other methods involving getDate() get unpredictable when you are around the start or end of a month.

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend your `javascript Date` object like this

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
    return this;
};

Date.prototype.substractDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() - days);
    return this;
};

     //then
var dateDiff=7;
var toDay = new Date();
var futureDay= new Date(toDay.addDays(dateDiff));
var prevDay = new Date(toDay.substractDays(dateDiff*2)); // substracted 14 daysbecause 'toDay' value has been incresed by 7 days
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for spotting I have corrected it check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeQ8r/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add /subtract   like following

```
var fdate= new Date();
var numberofdayes= 7;
fdate.setDate(fdate.getDate() + numberofdayes);
```

(Not sure whether you are asking that or not)

Then you can format it in dd/mm/yyyy using getDate(), getMonth() and getFullYear().
(Don't forget to add 1 to `fdate.getMonth()`)

```
var formateddate = fdate.getDate()+ '/'+ fdate.getMonth()+1 + '/'+ fdate.getFullYear();
```